# Technical Word for Moving Objects

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a technical word to describe objects that are travelling in parallel pathways but in opposite directions from each other. For instance on a highway you have two cars , one in the southbound lane and the other in the northbound lane, you would say the cars are .............(fill in the blank).

Comment: Avoid answering questions in comments. Post comments here only to [ask for more information or suggest improvements](/help/privileges/comment). Other types of comment can be posted in the [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) or a chatroom created for the purpose.

Comment: Avoid word or phrase requests that lack: (i) your criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: I suggest that belongs not to any English, but to first-year maths or physics degrees.

If you drop the *parallel*  and look at merely *opposite directions* it might well be covered in A-level, which outside the UK prolly equates to senior high school.

Answer (score 3):

[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/antiparallel) gives this definition of **antiparallel**:

> *antiparallel* adjective
>
> Physics
>
> Parallel but moving or oriented in opposite directions.

This fits your first two requirements (register and general definition) but would not fit your form and would not be suitable in most broadcast traffic commentaries.

Comment: Wow.  I would have guessed that would mean *perpendicular*.  After seeing the meaning I can understand how they arrived at that meaning but its use will probably lead to confusion unless it’s  well-explained.

Comment: @Jim Actually, this usage (parallel but opposite) is established. Had the term not been suggested already, I'd have added it as an answer.

Comment: @Lawrence - I’m not doubting it. I’m just saying that I’d never heard of It and that I would have guessed wrong about what it meant had I encountered it in the wild.

Comment: @Jim Ah, the world of technical terminology. Who'd have guessed that *normal* would have meant *perpendicular*! :)

Answer (score 1):

For traffic in particular, we have **oncoming cars**

> a car etc that is coming towards you

["oncoming car/traffic", From Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/oncoming-car-traffic-etc)

However, this is normally used from the vantage point of the street, or in close proximity to the traffic. It doesn't sound idiomatic to use it as a remote, conceptual description.